# AWS Lambda import error: Unable to import module "lambda_function"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a simple program in AWS Lambda. However, it is failing with `DEFAULT_CIPHERS` error. When I run the following program it **fails** with error `...unable to import lambda function`:

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file = '2011-02-12-0.json.gz'
    download_res = requests.get(f"https://data.gharchive.org/{file}")
    print(f"Files downloaded successfully - Filename: {file}")
    os.environ.setdefault('AWS_PROFILE', 'myid')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    upload_res = s3.put_object(Bucket='my-demo-bucket3', Key=file, Body=download_res.content)
    print("Files Uploaded successfully")
    return upload_res
```

**Error**:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/var/task/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "5d82baed-2ee6-41cd-a8e7-d24a59061dbc",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Can anyone please help me sort this out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the versioning of the packages. The difference in these 2 codes that makes the problem is `boto3`. There's an open issue on GitHub related to this.
A solution, as several people wrote there would be to pin down the version of `urllib3`

You can put something like this in your requirements.txt

```
requests
urllib3<2
```

The second option is to pin down the `requests` package to `2.29.0`, as 2 guys mentioned this fixed issue with their Lambda functions.

To track the progress of this, you can check the issue in [Github](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6443)

Comment: thanks for replying. Could you please elaborate on the requirements.txt. I am not sure I got this. New to Lambda, so if you can help with the actual code, it will be great ! thanks

Comment: When you install python packages that you use, the best practice is to create requirements.txt file and install requirements with this command: `pip install -r requirements.txt` When doing it for Lambda functions, you should also use -t option, to install all the requirements in a folder, so you can zip it and upload it to AWS Lambda

Comment: i am a newbie and i did not use requiremnt.txt as I was following instructions from a tutorial. i used `pip install requests -t myfolder` . I even tried downgrading like u mentioned as: `python -m pip install requests "urllib3<2"`. However it failed with `Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./demo-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.30.0). Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2 in ./demo-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.26.15)` etc. Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: @marie20 on AWS Lambda console, have you visually checked if "requests" package is set to "2.29.0"?